# How to list/print multiple values in an array continuously?

Tags: c, arrays, date

I'm new to C and am writing a program that takes today's date as provided by the user, compares it to a few stored dates, and calculates the number of days it has been since the stored dates.

The date given by the user (today's date) is stored in an array of 10 chars: `mm/dd/yyyy`

I've declared this array as `char today [10];`

I've prompted the user to enter a date with: `char *todaysdate = get_string;` 
and stored each value of that string in `today[]`

`today[0]` and `today[1]` represent `mm` in the date.

For example, today's date is `06/17/2018` and `today[0] = 0`, and `today[1] = 6`

I've already created a struct for today's date, comprised of `present.month`, `present.day`, and `present.year`.

If I want to store the value for the month (06) in `present.month` how can I do this? I'm not having any luck with:

```
//store this date in the Date struct called present
present.month = today[0]today[1];
eprintf("Month of today's date is: %d", present.month);
```

**I don't want to perform arithmetic on `today[0]` and `today[1]`, 
I just want to list them back to back.**

Here's my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct {
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
} Date;

int main (void) {
    // declare the dates used in the program
    Date AS_bday;
    Date DR_bday;
    Date TF_bday;
    Date present;

    // create a day counter of some sort, to calculate number of days between today and the birthdays
    //int AS_count = 0;
    //int DR_count = 0;
    //int TF_count = 0;

    // specify the Birthdays
    AS_bday.month = 03;
    AS_bday.day = 21;
    AS_bday.year = 2014;

    DR_bday.month = 04;
    DR_bday.day = 01;
    DR_bday.year = 2016;

    TF_bday.month = 11;
    TF_bday.day = 12;
    TF_bday.year = 2017;

    // create an array of chars to represent today's date
    char today[10];

    // prompt the user to enter today's date in mm/dd/yyyy using get_string
    // store that date as a string

    printf("Enter today's date (mm/dd/yyyy):");
    char *todaysdate = get_string();

    // extract the digits from the string using isdigit and store them in today[]
    // store the / marks in today[]

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(todaysdate); i++) {
        if (isdigit(todaysdate[i])) {
            today[i] = (todaysdate[i] - 48);
            eprintf("Value of today's date is %d", today[i]);
        } else {
            today[i] = todaysdate[i];
            eprintf("Should print a slash: %c", today[i]);
        }
    }

    //store this date in the present Date struct
    present.month = today[0]today[1];
    eprintf("Month of today's date is: %d", present.month);
}
```

Lastly, I'm sure there is a much cleaner way to write this program, but I'm very new to programming. I'm open to suggestions on a better way to implement this program as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to do arithmetic. `today[0]today[1]` is just not valid C. This should work:

```
present.month = (today[0] * 10) + today[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

As cfillion was saying you would have to do the arithmetic because you are getting the dates as string from the user and you want to store them in a integer variable inside your structure.

So you have two options

#### 1. Do the arithmetic

```
   present.month = ( (today[0]-48) * 10 ) + (today[1] -48);
```

It is necessary to subtract 48 to the value because characters are being stored as ASCII values.[image]

As you can see in the table, the numbers have the ASCII values from 48 to 57, that's why you need to make that subtract in order to convert them.

#### 2. Redifine your structure to hold strings

```
typedef struct {
  char[2] month;
  char[2] day;
  char[4] year;
} Date;
```

This way, you could assign the value without doing arithmetic, as follows

```
present.month[0] = today[0];
present.month[1] = today[1];
```